# Pyoocalc couldn't import uno

Tags: python-3.x

Iam trying to insert data into libreoffice using uno in python 
but when i try to import uno iam getting

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/uno/**init**.py", line 4, in 
from base import Element, Css, Payload, UnoBaseFeature, UnoBaseField

iam using python 3.5 and i have installed python3-uno

following https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1065823/PyOOCalc-Python-Libre-Open-Office-Calc-Interface-A

Note:import pyoocalc imports uno

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04, add the line:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-package
```

into ~/.bashrc and execute:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```